# Java - Retrive Indivudual Values from a List in a Map

Tags: java, list, arraylist, iteration, treemap

I have a TreeMap with 3 entries, all from individual ArrayLists.

I use the following code:

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapOne = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> listFour = Arrays.asList("");

ArrayList<String> listOne = new ArrayList<>();
listOne.add("Writer");
listOne.add("Actor");
listOne.add("Politician");
listOne.add("Dancer");

ArrayList<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<>();
listTwo.add("James");
listTwo.add("Robert");
listTwo.add("Tereza");
listTwo.add("John");

ArrayList<String> listThree = new ArrayList<>();
listThree.add("Joyce");
listThree.add("Redford");
listThree.add("May");
listThree.add("Travolta");

for (int i = 0; i < listOne.size(); i++) {

    String stringOne = listOne.get(i);
    String stringTwo = listTwo.get(i);
    String stringThree = listThree.get(i);

    listFour = Arrays.asList(stringTwo, stringThree);

    mapOne.put(stringOne, listFour);

}
```

Now I want to obtain the individual String values from the sorted list. like so:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : mapOne.entrySet()) {

    String key = entry.getKey();

    for (String value : entry.getValue()) {

        System.out.println(value);

    }
}
```

The above code prints a list like

```
{Robert Redford , John Travolta , Tereza May , James Joyce}
```

Is it possible to iterate over the list in a way as to obtain to separate lists, one with the first names and the other with the last names?

```
listOne = {Robert , John , Tereza, James}
listTwo = {Redford, Travolta, May, Joyce}
```

Or should I use an entirely different approach?

The whole thing started out with the need to sort one ArrayList and to other accordingly. What seemed trivial at the beginning, turned out to be a real challenge.

I am a sort of a hobby programmer, so the pros out there kindly bear with me.

Comment: *The whole thing started out with the need to sort one ArrayList and to other accordingly.*: and the whole thing, including this sort, would be trivial if you used objects instead of using parallel lists. Use a single List<Person>, where Person is a class with a firstName, a lastName, and a profession. You can then sort the persons by first name, or by last name, or by profession.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the approach. I looked into the idea before, but had difficulties implementing it. Would you happen to have a few more details, a link or a snippet?

Comment: `list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstName))`. This sorts a list of persons by first name. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I would appreciate some more detail on using a public class like : Person {
   public String profession;
   public String name;
   public String surname;
} in my code. I do recognize that my query must sound amateurish, but I am very willing to learn something.

Comment: @rainer I updated the answer with an example of custom Comparator. Sorry JB Nizet, tell me if you want me to remove that part so you can post an answer.

Comment: @LppEdd no worries.

Comment: @rainer Avoid public fields. Use getters to access the state of the objects. Regarding how to define and use classes: there are entire books written about that. You can start with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: @JBNizet  "there are entire books written about that" ... I get this sometimes,  but the suggestion to buy and read a book it is actually not very helpful when I am in the middle of something and need a quick input. Thanks anyway for putting into the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're *over-engineering* somehow.

I will answer with a `Stream` solution first, just for the sake of trying it.
Note that I'd, personally, prefer the "old" iterative approach (see below).

```
// You can see by the use of AtomicInteger that this isn't the right road to take!
final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();
final Collection<List<String>> values1 =
        mapOne.values()
              .stream()
              .flatMap(v -> v.stream())
              .collect(partitioningBy(o -> i.getAndIncrement() % 2 != 0))
              .values();
```

Output: `[[Robert, John, Tereza, James], [Redford, Travolta, May, Joyce]]`

---

Iterative approach

```
final Collection<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
final Collection<String> surnames = new ArrayList<>();

for (final List<String> value : mapOne.values()) {
    names.add(value.get(0));
    surnames.add(value.get(1));
}
```

Output:

```
[Robert, John, Tereza, James]
[Redford, Travolta, May, Joyce]
```

This is safe because you know each inner `List` has two elements.

---

What JB Nizet is telling you to do (credit to him for writing that), is basically to create an appropriate `class`

```
public class Person {
   private String profession;
   private String name;
   private String surname;

   // Getters and setters. JavaBean style
}
```

And proceed to sort a `Collection<Person>`.
For example, keeping it as simple as possible

```
final List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

// Populate list

Collections.sort(persons, (p1, p2) -> {
    // Not null-safe
    return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
});
```

This will sort the list by `name`. It will not return a new List, but simply modify the input one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this well explained answer. The solutions works perfectly. My mantra usually is keeping things simple and I did have the impression that I was  over-engineering, as you mention above.

Answer (score 0):

Putting all the valuable tips, online searches and my efforts together, this is my final solution (in the hope that it might be useful to others). It seems to me my solution is minimal and straightforward  :

```
    List<Sites> listOfSites = new ArrayList<Sites>();

    for (int i = 0; i < classLists.listSites.size(); i++) {

        String site = classLists.listSites.get(i);   
        String description = classLists.listSitesDesc.get(i);
        String link = classLists.listSitesLinks.get(i);

        listOfSites.add(new Sites(site, description, link));

    }

    Collections.sort(listOfSites, (p1, p2) -> {

        return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());

    });

    final ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Sites s : listOfSites) {

        String name = s.getName();
        String description = s.getDesc();
        String link = s.getLink();

        titles.add(name);
        descriptions.add(description);
        links.add(link);

    }
```

Below the class Sites:

```
public class Sites implements Comparable<Sites> {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String link;

    public Sites(String name, String description, String link) {

        this.name  = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {

        this.name = name;

    }

    public String getDesc() {

        return description;
    }

    public void setDesc(String description) {

        this.description = description;

    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {

        this.link = link;

    }

}
```